Convergence of rays at focal plane after reflection from concave mirror
My teacher taught us that rays parallel to each other(but not necessarily parallel to the principal axis), after reflection from a concave mirror,get converged at a sharp point somewhere on the focal plane.He didn't provide any formal explanation.
I have 2 doubts here:

How do we know all the rays necessarily converge at a single point? I mean, i know it's the property of concave mirrors to converge light rays, but it would be nice to know the proof, maybe a geometrical one.
How do we know the point at which they all converge is necessarily on the focal plane?
I've tried to prove it, but have been unsuccessful at it
I'm a high school student so a simple yet convincing proof is expected.


Concave mirrors have a basic property: they can focus parallel rays of light to a single point. Let's explore the why behind this magic using some basic geometry.
Imagine a ray (think arrow!) parallel to the principal axis (a fancy term for the mirror's center line) striking the mirror. The reflection law guarantees the reflected ray makes the same angle with the mirror's surface as the incoming ray. Now, consider triangles formed by the mirror's center, the point of incidence, and the intersection points of the incident and reflected rays with the principal axis. These triangles are similar by the AA postulate (shared right angle and a common side). Since the incoming ray is parallel, the angle it makes with the axis is zero. This translates, through triangle similarity, to the reflected ray also intersecting the axis at zero degrees – precisely at the focal point (designated by F). This holds true for any parallel ray striking the mirror, leading to all reflected rays converging at F.
The focal plane, a plane perpendicular to the principal axis passing through F, captures this convergence beautifully. Even if the initial parallel rays weren't perfectly aligned in a plane perpendicular to the axis, their converged portions at F will all lie within the focal plane. This is because any reflected ray intersecting the axis at F must also be part of this "focusing plane."

how to prove the last part, that parallel rays at an angle to the principal axis converge at the focal plane ONLY.

Tilted parallel rays converge at F, but only the portion intersecting the focal plane (defined by axis and F) captures all converged rays. Any ray reaching F from any angle must be in this plane, as for a ray to hit F, it must reflect at an angle that intersects the principal axis at F. Since the focal plane is defined by being perpendicular to the axis at F, any ray passing through F inherently lies within that plane. Focal plane acts as a filter.

An arbitrary concave mirror does not necessarily reflect incoming parallel rays into a single focal point. A true parabolic mirror does reflect rays that are parallel with its symmetry axis to and through a single point, focus, a fact that was known to Archimedes, but it does not reflect any other ray that are not parallel with the axis thorough a single point. Not just that there is no single point of convergence for such rays but the size of that error measured in some well-defined geometric sense increase with the angle the ray makes with the mirror's axis (coma error). The basic problem and the solution of that problem is the fundamental task of optical design is to define and classify these and similar errors and suggest methods to minimize them; look up stigmatism and related subjects such as Abbe's sine condition, Schwarzschild mirrors, etc.; this has been an active research area since the 1600s.

All rays actually don't converge to a single point. The same problem occurs for lenses. But for real mirrors and lenses, they are pretty close.
Often is the different rays focus into a small enough spot that it works well enough. For example in a simple magnifying glass doesn't need to be perfect. On the other hand, a camera lens needs a spot to be not much bigger than a wavelength of light for clear images.
Figuring out how to make all rays focus to the same point is the chief difficulty of lens design. There are several categories of imperfection of this sort.
The biggest error is usually spherical aberration. The surface of a lens or mirror has to be extremely accurate to focus all rays to an extremely small spot. For centuries, a sphere was the only shape that it was possible to make to the required accuracy. If you rub two surfaces together, high spots tend to grind off, leaving a sphere.
The ideal shape for a surface is a paraboloid or hyperboloid. Fortunately, for relatively small diameter lenses and mirrors with large radius spherical surfaces, a sphere is almost exactly the ideal shape. But the rays near the center come to a focus at a slightly different distance than edge rays. This difference is spherical aberration.
Chromatic aberration is another problem for lenses. The index of refraction of many glasses changes with wavelength. So the focal length of different colors is slightly different. This makes colored rings around a point.
There are several other categories of imperfection.
The fix is to make a compound lens, or to use a lens together with a mirror. You design one element to have imperfections that compensate for other elements, so the total is closer to perfect.
There is one imperfection that cannot be fixed this way. Diffraction is the spreading out of light because it is a wave. If you pass light through a pinhole, it spreads out into a diffraction pattern. The smaller the pinhole, the bigger the diffraction pattern.
A lens or mirror can be thought of as a very large pinhole. This causes a very small diffraction pattern. But a focal spot must be very small indeed to be small enough. The only way to make diffraction smaller is to make lens and mirror diameters bigger. And this usually makes the geometric aberrations worse, or at least harder to design around.
A lens or mirror where diffraction is the biggest problem is said to be diffraction limited. This is a good as you can get. And it is typically expensive.
However, you don't consider aberrations and diffraction when you are designing a simple system, or when laying out the start of a complex system. You assume spherical surfaces are perfect. You use the rays that are very close to the axis, because those are the ones that behave the most perfectly. You use this to lay out the basic properties of the system, such as the overall focal length.
You might design a two lens telescope or a telescope with a mirror and an eyepiece this way. Then you see that simple lenses aren't good enough.
You might buy double or triplet lenses, which are two or three lenses glued together. These have already had their aberrations minimized. Two such lenses, or one lens and a mirror might have small enough aberrations for your purpose.
If not, you have to do a full design. This typically makes small changes that incrementally improve things. It takes specialized software and lots of experience.
Or it is now possible to cast aspherical shapes with enough precision for some uses.
